# PySpark UDF returns a string but I need an integer

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have this code, where I return from UDF an Integer type, but system change this to string.

How can I correct this?

```
# Define a UDF to determine the number of pixels per image
def dogPixelCount(doglist):
totalpixels = 0
for dog in doglist:
    totalpixels += (dog[3] - dog[1]) * (dog[4] - dog[2])
return totalpixels

# Define a UDF for the pixel count
udfDogPixelCount = F.udf(dogPixelCount, IntegerType())
joined_df = joined_df.withColumn('dog_pixels', udfDogPixelCount('dogs'))

# Create a column representing the percentage of pixels
joined_df = joined_df.withColumn('dog_percent', ('dog_pixels' / sum('dog_pixels') ) * 100 )

# Show the first 10 annotations with more than 60% dog
joined_df.filter(dog_percent > 60).show(10)
```

Comment: Please do not SHOUT when posting here. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand, and won't help you get answers any faster. It's also rather impolite to be SHOUTING at us when you're asking us for free help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, just use the simple syntax x = int(String), for example:

```
num = '10'
  
# check and print type num variable 
print(type(num))  
  
# convert the num into string  
converted_num = int(num) 
  
# print type of converted_num 
print(type(converted_num)) 
  
# We can check by doing some mathematical operations 
print(converted_num + 20)
```

```
result:
<class 'str'>
<class 'int'>
30
```

to convert your string to integer. So let put **int (YourStringNeededToConvert)** to change it into integer.

Answer (score 0):

Without full context, it looks like you need to use the `col`/`sum`functions from `pyspark.sql.functions`, as rather than the string of the column name (`dog_pixels`) and the inbuilt `sum` function. Try this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
...

joined_df = joined_df.withColumn('dog_percent', (F.col('dog_pixels') / F.sum('dog_pixels') ) * 100 )
```